# How to get "Graph API Object ID" for cURL to Linter tool?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to ping the Facebook linter using the following script which accepts a URL.

It keeps giving me the error:

```
{
  "error":{
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fgoogle.com",
    "type":"OAuthException",
    "code":803
  }
}
```

If I go to the actual linter tool though, and put in `http://google.com`, at the bottom it will generate a URL that looks like this:

`https://graph.facebook.com/381702034999`

If I take that ID and put it back into my code in place of a URL suddenly it works.

How do I go about doing this? It should take a URL as input:

```
<?

  $url = urlencode($_GET['url']);

  $access_token = "APP_ID|APP_SECRET";
  $params = array(
    'id' => $url,
    'scrape' => 'true',
    'access_token' => $access_token
  );

  $ch = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com");
  curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $params
  ));

  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  echo $result;
```

Comment: What is your question? Sorry but its not clear at all that what exactly you want to do

Comment: I'm trying to bust the cache on a url using the FB linter tool via curl. I am getting an 803 error when i give it a URL for the object. how do I bust the cache on a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this happens because you might use the wrong encoding... If I try it with

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&scrape=true&access_token={access_token}
```

I get the following result:

```
{
   "id": "http://google.com",
   "shares": 8654603,
   "comments": 133590
}
```